# can't use log analytics workspace in a different subscription? terraform azurerm policy assignment

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy, azure-rm

I'm using terraform to write azure policy as code
I found two problems
1 I can't seem to use log analytics workspace that is on a different subscription, within same subscription, it's fine
2 For policies that needs managed identity, I can't seem to assign correct rights to it.

```
resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "Enable_Azure_Monitor_for_VMs" {
  
  name                 = "Enable Azure Monitor for VMs"
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/55f3eceb-5573-4f18-9695-226972c6d74a"
  description          = "Enable Azure Monitor for the virtual machines (VMs) in the specified scope (management group, subscription or resource group). Takes Log Analytics workspace as parameter."
  display_name         = "Enable Azure Monitor for VMs"
  location             = var.location
  metadata = jsonencode(
    {
      "category" : "General"
  })

  parameters = jsonencode({
    "logAnalytics_1" : {
      "value" : var.log_analytics_workspace_ID
    }
  })

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vm_policy_msi_assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_policy_assignment.Enable_Azure_Monitor_for_VMs.scope
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_policy_assignment.Enable_Azure_Monitor_for_VMs.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

for var.log_analytics_workspace_ID, if i use the workspace id that is in the same subscription as the policy, it would work fine. but If I use a workspace ID from a different subscription, after deployment, the workspace field will be blank.

also for

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vm_policy_msi_assignment"
```

, I have already given myself user access management role, but after deployment, "This identity currently has the following permissions:" is still blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to my own question:)
1 this is not something designed well in Azure, I recon.
MS states "a Managed Identity (MSI) is created for each policy assignment that contains DeployIfNotExists effects in the definitions. The required permission for the target assignment scope is managed automatically. However, if the remediation tasks need to interact with resources outside of the assignment scope, you will need to manually configure the required permissions."

which means, the system generated managed identity which needs access in log analytics workspace in  **another subscription** need to be manually with **log analytics workspace contributor** rights
Also since you can't user user generated managed ID, you can't pre-populate this.
so if you want to to achieve in terraform, it seems you have to run policy assignment twice, the first time is just to get ID, then manual ( or via script) to assign permission, then run policy assignment again to point to the resource..

2 The ID was actually given the contributor rights, you just have to go into sub RBAC to see it.